# excel-distribution function

Tags: statistics

I have an exercise in statistics in witch I need to generate n values ​​of a random variable X having the distribution function F ( in excel ). I don't understand how I should do that in excel.

[image]

Comment: Find the inverse of the cumulative distribution function $F$ and apply that to a uniformly distributed random variable on $(0,1)$.  Do this $n$ times

Answer (score 0):

Excel has this $\texttt{RAND()}$ function which samples from a uniform distribution over $[0,1]$. You can use this in order to sample from other distributions using the following trick.

Let $Y$ be another random variable with uniform distribution function over $[0,1]$. The idea is to sample from $Y$, apply some function $g(Y)$ to it and hopefully obtain something distributed as the given cumulative distribution $F(X)$ you have. Let $X = g(Y)$. We know that both cumulative distributions (of $X$ and $Y$ )must be related as
$$
F(x) = \int_0^{y}dy
$$
since $Y$ is uniformly distributed. Hence $F(x) = y\in[0,1]$ so that $x = F^{-1}(y)$. In your case:
$$
F(x) = 1-e^{-x}\implies F^{-1}(y) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{1-y}\right)
$$
Hence, the resulting command would be:
$$\texttt{=ln(1/(1-RAND()))}$$

Hope this helps.